# Построить отрицание произвольного регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

#### Преамбула

Регулярные выражения в программировании часто используются для валидации строк символов. Задача выяснить, удовлетворяет ли какая строка заданному выражению, довольно часто возникает при написании программ. Весьма распространены регулярки и во всяких конфигурационных файлах, настройках. Но если в тексте программы можно воспользоваться обычным оператором отрицания из языка программирования, в конфигах ситуация может быть сложнее. Допустим, нужно применить некоторую секцию конфигурации, только если строка с условием не начинается с некой подстроки, хотя синтаксис конфига позволяет только позитивную проверку (удовлетворяет ли строка регулярному выражению).

Итак, поскольку такая проблема слишком часто заводит меня в тупик, решил сформулировать её в более общем виде.

#### Постановка задачи

Пусть дано регулярное выражение `R`, содержащее любую, произвольную, заранее неизвестную комбинацию токенов, грамматически верную для движка [PCRE](https://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html). Требуется найти регулярное выражение `!R`, язык которого является дополнением для языка `R`. То есть любая строка, подходящая под `R`, не подходит под `!R` и наоборот.

Существует ли решение в общем виде? Если да, то предпочтительно включающее `R` в качестве подвыражения.

Comment: Это слишком общая задача. Всё зависит от того, что имеется в виду под "отрицанием". "Не начинается", "не содержит", "не заканчивается"... В общем виде, `^Хочу то, хочу это$` != `^(?!Хочу то, хочу это$).*$` можно использовать для нахождения любой строки кроме исключаемой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть `R` - любое валидное регулярное выражение, тогда регулярное выражение его дополняющее:

```
(?![\s\S]*R)\A[\s\S]*\Z
```

Объяснять тут особо нечего - захватываем ТОЛЬКО весь текст, если где-то внутри него нет соответствия шаблону `R`.

https://regex101.com/r/Kqd1qU/1

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл более простой вариант дополняющего регулярного выражения аналогичному тому, что предложил @ReinRaus.

```
^(?!.*R)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Kqd1qU/11/tests